# Ignore else from CASE in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way to avoid the else part when CASE is used ? For example below is the case STATUS column should display only A or B and there should not any NULL

```
    (CASE
     WHEN …..
     THEN 'A'
     WHEN … 
     THEN 'B'  
     END) as STATUS
```

Comment: If everything matches the `THEN` clauses, then you will not get `NULL`.

Comment: There is a chance that THEN clause might not match but still is there a way to ignore it because there will be only A and B and no there different value should be present.

Comment: If there is a chance that there isn't an A nor a B, and that chance happens... what value do you want to see returned as the status?

Comment: @HereGoes I do not want that record to be displayed at all if it's not A nor B

Comment: Then in the WHERE clause you need to specify WHERE x = 'A' or x = 'B'

Comment: Then I would think you'd want to use the IN clause on a WHERE statement... WHERE status IN ('A',B')

Comment: @HereGoes Ok this STATUS is an alias name and the table does not have any field like that so placing a where clause as status in ('A','B') gives and error as the SQLERRMC=STATUS since its alias name. Please note that in the case I am validating some date fields.

Comment: Then you are back to the OR clause... WHERE (condition for case when A OR condition for case when B)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
--ORIGINAL COLUMNS / EXPRESSIONS 
, (CASE
     WHEN ... THEN 'A'
     WHEN ... THEN 'B'  
     END) as STATUS
FROM ...
)
WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL
```